# Unexpected behavior of useLocation() hook in React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I am trying to work on a personal project where I'm making an online auction site. Currently, I am trying to render a product details page whenever a user clicks on a specific product to buy. On the first click it works as expected and the details are rendered correctly. But everything breaks when I refresh the page.

Product Details Component:

```
function ProductDetails() {
  const location = useLocation();
  const [product, setProduct] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    const id = location.pathname;
    console.log(id);
    axios
      .get(id)
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.status === 200) {
          setProduct(response.data);
          setDate(response.data.bidEnd);
        } else console.log(response);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }, []);

  //returns HTML code;
}
```

when the route `"/products/<some_id>"` is hit, I use this code to make a call to my backend to fetch the data. On the first instance I receive the proper id on backend, but when I refresh a get call is made to `"/products/styles.css"`.

Relevant App.jsx code:

```
const Routing = () => {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
      <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
      <Route path="/signup" element={<Signup />} />

      <Route path="/addproduct" element={<AddProduct />} />
      <Route path="/bidandbuy" element={<BidAndBuy />} />
      <Route path="/products/:id" element={<ProductDetails />} />

      <Route path="/profile" element={<Profile />} />
    </Routes>
  );
};

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar />
      <Routing />
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Relevant node backend code:

```js
app.route("/products/:id").get((req, res) => {
  console.log(req.params); //prints { id: 'styles.css' } after refresh
  const id = req.params.id;

  Product.findOne({ _id: id })
    .populate("seller")
    .then((response) => res.status(200).send(response))
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
});
```

I am totally clueless as to what is happening so any help is appreciated.

EDIT 1:
I tried using the `useParams()` hook instead of `useLocation()` and it produced the same problem(receiveing `{ id: 'styles.css' }` in backend after refreshing). So now I am thinking it's not an issue with the hook but with something with the way I have set up the app. Still no clue as to how to solve it though.

Comment: What happens when you refresh?

Comment: @Konrad blank page on front end, nothing loads. On backend the console.log(req.params) prints { id: 'styles.css' } whereas I expect it to print something like this { id: '64d51eccd391aecc0bc89400' }.

Comment: How do you serve react app?

Comment: Right now just on my localhost

Comment: What is `useLocation`? Which routing library, and which version of it, are you using?

Comment: It is a react router hook. I imported it like this 
`import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";`

The version of react-router-dom is 6.14.2 in my package.json file.

Comment: How are you building and serving the app, e.g. what commands/scripts? Whatever you are using, it should be configured to return the root index.html file for ***all*** page requests into the app.

Comment: I used `npx create-react-app .` to initialize the project. Then I changed the start script in my package.json to `"set PORT=3003 && react-scripts start"` since I was already using port 3000 for another application. Then I use `npm start` to start my application. I am pretty new to this and do not quite understand what you mean by return the root index.html for all page requests into the app. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Do you get any errors in the browser console?

Comment: No, nothing in my browser console. The only error that happens on refresh is on my backend due to id value being a string and not an actual id.

Answer (score -1):

try setting your **use-Effect dependency to your pathname** so every time your id changes you call your api
something like this:

```
const id = location.pathname;
     useEffect(() => {
   
    console.log(id);
    axios
      .get(id)
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.status === 200) {
          setProduct(response.data);
          setDate(response.data.bidEnd);
        } else console.log(response);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }, [id]);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for the response. Unfortunately, I tried this and it didn't fix the problem. It still happens exactly the same way.